# FFT realforward vs realforwardfull in example

Tags: java, fft

I am exploring the JTransforms FFT and I tried `FFT.realForward()` and `FFT.realForwardFull()` and  I got these results:

```
RealForward

16.236587494
-2.3513066039999995    <----------------?
1.8268368691062924
-1.1179067733368138
6.698362081000001
5.353354667
-6.146021583106291
-12.013420149336813


RealForwardFull
16.236587494
0.0                      <------------------
1.8268368691062924
-1.1179067733368138
6.698362081000001
5.353354667
-6.146021583106291
-12.013420149336813
-2.3513066039999995  <-----------------
0.0                    <-------------
-6.146021583106291
12.013420149336813
6.698362081000001
-5.353354667
1.8268368691062924
1.1179067733368138
```

So, as you can see, `realforwardFull()` gave a different imaginary for the first number and add a new pair. Shouldn't `realforward()` produce the same results minus any duplication?

Comment: Why the downvote,, verry valid question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the FFT of a real signal is symmetrical, both the k=0 and k=N/2 components are real-only (you can see that in the "full" output).  So they're packed together in the "non-full" output.

This output layout is explained in the JavaDoc.

(Note: FFTW does the same thing.)

Answer (score 0):

For information on how your FFT output data is represented look at the JTransforms documentation [HERE](http://incanter.org/docs/parallelcolt/api/edu/emory/mathcs/jtransforms/fft/DoubleFFT_1D.html#realForward(double[]))

For RealForwardFull the output is the Full FFT data the usual way, i.e N-Complex numbers, with the real and imaginary components interleaved.

For RealForward the output is arranged as follows: -The first two elements are the real components of the first ( k = 0 ) and the middle ( k = N/2 ) FFT coefficients respectively, the rest of the FFT coefficients are then given after that with the real and imaginary components interleaved.

Like Oli CharlesWorth has mentioned, the imaginary component of the k = 0 and k = N/2 terms will be zero because the input signal is real, so Realforward does not return them.It only returns the minimum information enough for you to be able to reconstruct the full spectrum.